# What is the name of this thick, square uppercase?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to find the font used in the image below. I used myfont as well whatfont is websites but did not get the exact font. Can anybody can help me to find the name of the font?

https://99designs.com/profiles/dsevarika/designs/1322588

Answer (score 1):

[Khepri Font](https://www.pixelsurplus.com/freebies/khepri-free-modern-egyptian-typeface) with a custom design for the letter "C"

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user139363 you may upvote or accept (checkmark) the answer if it was useful